# create pyspark dataframe from numpy array and concatenate with other pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to convert a numpy array into pyspark dataframe in order to concatenate with other pyspark dataframes

```py
outlier_scores = outlier_scores.astype(int)
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'> [1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]

schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),StructField("outlier_scores", IntegerType(), True)

# Convert the NumPy array to a PySpark DataFrame
outlier_df = spark.createDataFrame(enumerate(outlier_scores), schema)

# Join the two DataFrames on the index column
result_df = df_assembled.join(outlier_df, df_assembled.index == outlier_df.id, "inner").drop("id")
```

Comment: see [`tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method of ndarray

Comment: @samkart that has worked , thanks for the direction